# How does JunOS device boot up ? Juniper JunOS Boot Process

Tags: juniper-junos

Sounds pretty basic , I could no where find answer for my below questions

Devices  : srx 345 , ex3300 (VC)

Inside a junOS device where is the image store path/.tgz , so that I can copy from one to another ?(example in a vc - i can copy from master to Line card)

In general can anyone explain the bootprocess (note:not how to boot from usb or tftp) on a Juniper device?
what happens to the .tgz file once its booted up? i dont see them in /altroot or /altconfig

Appreciate your response and thanks in advance

Comment: *request system snapshot* is the common method for backing up the installed OS. Many platforms can boot/install from that "backup" snapshot for recovery purposes.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Inside a junOS device where is the image store path/.tgz , so that I
> can copy from one to another ?(example in a vc - i can copy from
> master to Line card)

You as the operator decide where the installation file goes.  This is the file you'd reference in the `request system software` command.

Once installed, Junos is no longer contained in a single image file.  It is decompressed and the various installation packages that make up Junos are distributed across the filesystem.  You'd have to use the original installation file.

Since you're in a VC, you might be able to use the automatic software upgrade feature.  You'll have to have some form of access to the device to reboot it.  Check the [documentation](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/us/en/software/junos/virtual-chassis-qfx/topics/task/virtual-chassis-ex4200-software-automatic-update-ex-series-cli.html) for more details, note that it may not explicitly say EX3300, it should still work.

> In general can anyone explain the bootprocess (note:not how to boot
> from usb or tftp) on a Juniper device? what happens to the .tgz file
> once its booted up? i dont see them in /altroot or /altconfig

Junos and Junos Evo are based on FreeBSD and Linux respectively (depends on platform/version) and uses a bootloader, there is no single image.  The SRX345 and EX3300 run Junos (not Evo).

Comment: "Junos OS Evolved" is based on Linux. Everything prior to that is FreeBSD. (sometimes running as a VM under a linux KVM base system)

Comment: Good catch, @Ricky.  I updated my answer, missed the part about Evo.

Comment: Thank you guys @rickyandjordan , that explains a lot  on time spent on searching for a .tgz file all around Junos paths. (bad habit from folks with cisco exp!!! :))  In line with the boot topic, in Virutal Chassis , a member boot up with diffferent image , there is no way u can scp the current image from another member or master ..but need to use winscp or usb to boot up the device with new image?? is that right?